# jquery confict,checkbox becoming unclickable after adding a JavaScript script to your Blade template head

Tags: javascript, laravel

issue with the checkbox becoming unclickable after adding a JavaScript script to your Blade template head.
i am using test ui for tyro and also in the same page i using checkbox in my blade.
when i using tyro javascript url my UI's checkbox not working
i am trying to resolve the conflict but it's not work

```
<!-- Include jQuery and other scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r224/prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include iClient scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://iclientsimulator.test.tyro.com/iclient-with-ui-v1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Use noConflict to release control of the global variable TYRO
    var TYROUI_SIMULATOR = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://iclientsimulator.test.tyro.com/iclient-v1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Use noConflict to release control of the global variable TYRO
    var CUSTOMUI_SIMULATOR = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://iclient.test.tyro.com/iclient-with-ui-v1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Use noConflict to release control of the global variable TYRO
    var TYROUI_TEST = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://iclient.test.tyro.com/iclient-v1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Use noConflict to release control of the global variable TYRO
    var CUSTOMUI_TEST = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var system = [TYROUI_SIMULATOR, CUSTOMUI_SIMULATOR];
    var configurationURLs = ["https://iclientsimulator.test.tyro.com/configuration.html", "https://iclient.test.tyro.com/configuration.html"];
    var configurationUrl = configurationURLs[0];
    var apiKey = "8a28a6421856b38d22f46ad0b4721ab1"; // API Key not validated in either test environment
    var posProductInfo = {
        posProductVendor: "Foodship",
        posProductName: "Foodship POS",
        posProductVersion: "1.0.7"
    };
    var simulator = true;

    function showTransactionsPage() {
        hilightNavigationBar("transactions");
        showTransactionsNavigation();
        showPurchaseWithTyroUI();
    }

    function showReportingPage() {
        hilightNavigationBar("reporting");
        showReportingNavigation();
        showReconciliationReport();
    }

    function showConfigurationPage() {
        hilightNavigationBar("configuration");
        showConfigurationNavigation();
        showPairing();
    }

    function showTransactionsNavigation() {
        $("#navigation").html($("#transactionsNavigation").html());
    }

    function showReportingNavigation() {
        $("#navigation").html($("#reportingNavigation").html());
    }

    function showConfigurationNavigation() {
        $("#navigation").html($("#configurationNavigation").html());
    }

    function showPurchaseWithTyroUI() {
        hilightNavigation("purchaseWithTyroUI");
        $("#content").html($("#purchaseWithTyroUIContent").html());
    }

    function showRefundWithTyroUI() {
        hilightNavigation("refundWithTyroUI");
        $("#content").html($("#refundWithTyroUIContent").html());
    }

    function showPurchaseWithCustomUI() {
        hilightNavigation("purchaseWithCustomUI");
        $("#content").html($("#purchaseWithCustomUIContent").html());
    }

    function showRefundWithCustomUI() {
        hilightNavigation("refundWithCustomUI");
        $("#content").html($("#refundWithCustomUIContent").html());
    }

    function showSystemChoice() {
        hilightNavigation("systemChoice");
        $("#content").html($("#systemChoiceContent").html());
        if (simulator) {
            $("#simulator").click();
        } else {
            $("#test-system").click();
        }
    }

    function showReconciliationReport() {
        hilightNavigation("reconciliationReport");
        $("#content").html($("#reconciliationReportContent").html());
        $("#date").datepicker({
            "dateFormat": "yymmdd"
        });
        $("#date").val($.datepicker.formatDate('yymmdd', new Date()));
    }

    function showSettlement() {
        hilightNavigation("settlement");
        $("#content").html($("#settlementContent").html());
    }

    function showPairing() {
        hilightNavigation("pairing");
        $("#content").html($("#pairingContent").html());
        var iclient = new system[1].IClient(apiKey, posProductInfo);
        iclient.getConfiguration(function(config) {
            $("#mid").val(config.mid);
            $("#tid").val(config.tid);
        });
    }

    function showTerminalInfo() {
        hilightNavigation("terminalInfo");
        $("#content").html($("#terminalInfoContent").html());
    }

    function showBrowserCheck() {
        hilightNavigation("browserCheck");
        $("#content").html($("#browserCheckContent").html());
    }

    function hilightNavigationBar(selected) {
        if (!$("#" + selected).hasClass("active")) {
            $("#" + selected).addClass("active")
        }
        $("#navigation-bar").children("li").each(function(i) {
            if (this.id != selected) {
                $(this).removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }

    function hilightNavigation(selected) {
        if (!$("#" + selected).hasClass("active")) {
            $("#" + selected).addClass("active")
        }
        $("#navigation").children("li").each(function(i) {
            if (this.id != selected) {
                $(this).removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }

    $().ready(function() {
        showTransactionsPage();
    });
</script>
```

need to work both my checkbox and tyro SIMULATOR but here if i add javascript url for simulator my checkbox not working